# jQuery add value for data attributes by element’s id

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress site with svg vector map for shops. I want to add values for all data attributes inside the  elements related to the element’s id by jquery. For example:

```
<svg>
<g class=“shop” id=“215” data-title=“” data-open=“”></g>
<g class=“shop” id=“217” data-title=“” data-open=“”></g>
<g class=“shop” id=“218” data-title=“” data-open=“”></g>
…
</svg>


<script>

$(“.shop”).attr(“id”);

$(“.shop”).find(“data-title”).val(“shop-name(‘id’)”);

$(“.shop”).find(“data-open”).val(“shop-opening-hours(‘id’)”);

</script>
```

Result:

```
<svg>
<g class=“shop” id=“215” data-title=“shop-name(‘215’)” data-open=“shop-opening-hours(‘215’)”></g>

<g class=“shop” id=“217” data-title=“shop-name(‘217’)” data-open=“shop-opening-hours(‘217’)”></g>

<g class=“shop” id=“218” data-title=“shop-name(‘218’)” data-open=“shop-opening-hours(‘218’)”></g>

…
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
    $.each($('svg .shop'), function (i, el) {
        var el = $(el);
        var id = el.attr('id');
        el.attr('data-title',`shop-name('${id}')`);
        el.attr('data-open',`shop-opening-hours('${id}')`);
    });

    console.log($('svg').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
    <g class="shop" id="215" data-title="" data-open=""></g>
    <g class="shop" id="217" data-title="" data-open=""></g>
    <g class="shop" id="218" data-title="" data-open=""></g>
</svg>
```